# JSON Decode changing values in array

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach, decode

I am using JSON to store results for brackets

Upper bracket stores 15 matches
Lower bracket stores 14 matches
Finals has 3 matches

I have decoded the JSON and want to be store a new result with given match number and given score results. I have tried with the foreach loops, the only problem is the the brackets are not grouping by rounds and not giving the commas after each result.

echo json_encode($results);

will give out

```
[0,0][0,0][0,0][0,0][3,5][0,0][0,0][0,0]
[0,0][0,0][0,0][0,0]
[0,0][0,0]
[0,0]
```

when i want it to give out

```
[
  [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[3,5],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
  [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
  [[0,0],[0,0]],
  [[0,0]]
]
```

Second question $match variable loops increments by rounds
so it give out:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,1,2,1
```

when I want it to give out

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
```

Any help is appreciated thank you. Below is the code:

```
<?php

$upper_bracket_results = "
[
[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
[[0,0],[0,0]],
[[0,0]]
]
";

$lower_bracket_results = "
[
[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
[[0,0],[0,0]],
[[0,0],[0,0]],
[[0,0]],
[[0,0]]
]
";

$final_bracket_results = "
[
[[0,0],[0,0]],
[[0,0]]
]
";


$json = "{\"results\" : [ {$upper_bracket_results} , {$lower_bracket_results} ,  {$final_bracket_results} ]}";

$allResults = json_decode($json, true);
$results = current($allResults); 

$upper = $results[0];
$lower = $results[1];
$final = $results[2];

$all = array_merge($results[0], $results[1], $results[2]);

$matchno = 2;
$score1 = 3;
$score2 = 5;

if($matchno <= 15)
{
    $bracket = $upper;
}
elseif($matchno >= 16 && $matchno <= 29)
{
    $bracket = $lower;
}
elseif($matchno >= 30 && $matchno <= 32)
{
    $bracket = $final;
}

foreach($bracket as $match => $result[0])
{
    foreach($result[0] as $match => $result)
    {
        $match += 1;

        if($match == $matchno)
        {
            $result[0] = $score1;
            $result[1] = $score2;
        }

        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: Don't create your own json. Just use `json_encode()` because php will parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with this code.

You use $match in the outer loop and the inner loop. This variable will get overwritten in the inner loop.

$result is used outside the loops and also as the value in both the loops.

```
foreach($bracket as $match => $result[0])
{
    foreach($result[0] as $match => $result)
    {
        $match += 1;

        if($match == $matchno)
        {
            $result[0] = $score1;
            $result[1] = $score2;
        }

        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
```

I don't clearly understand your desired output but having made some guesses, please see if this does what you want.

```
<?php
$upper = 
[
[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
[[0,0],[0,0]],
[[0,0]]
];

$lower =
[
[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]],
[[0,0],[0,0]],
[[0,0],[0,0]],
[[0,0]],
[[0,0]]
];

$final = 
[
[[0,0],[0,0]],
[[0,0]]
];



$matchno = 2;
$score1 = 3;
$score2 = 5;

if($matchno <= 15)
{
    $description = "Upper";
    $bracket = $upper;
    $offset = 0;
}
elseif($matchno >= 16 && $matchno <= 29)
{
    $description = "Lower";
    $bracket = $lower;
    $offset = 16;
}
elseif($matchno >= 30 && $matchno <= 32)
{
    $description = "Final";
    $bracket = $final;
    $offset = 30;
}

$matchNumberInBlock = 0;
echo "$description\n";
foreach($bracket as $i => $round)
{
    foreach($round as $j => $match)
    {
        $matchNumberInBlock++;

        if ( $matchNumberInBlock + $offset == $matchno )
        {
            $bracket[$i][$j][0] = $score1;
            $bracket[$i][$j][1] = $score2;
        }

    }
}
echo json_encode($bracket);
echo "\n";
```

Comment: thanks this worked just fine! i just had to change $matchNumberInBlock to $matchNumberInBlock = -1; for the lower and finals.

Comment: I see the problem. You could have moved $matchNumberInBlock++ after the if statement.